# Не могу применить .change к <input type="radio">

Tags: html, jquery

Доброго времени суток,

Пример моего кода:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="input-option13">
    <div class="radio">

        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="option[242]" value="1">
            <input type="radio" name="option[242]" value="2">
            <input type="radio" name="option[242]" value="3">
        </label>

    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $("input[type='radio'][name^='option']").change(function() {
        // Check input( $( this ).val() ) for validity here
        alert("hello");
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

На изменение radio не выскакивает alert.

В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не загружен jQuery, добавьте перед Вашим скриптом

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: 6 утра, извините

Comment: Держитесь. Хорошего Вам настроения!